# C# uncaught exception in try / catch block

Tags: c#, encryption

Consider a WPF application which uses a cryptographic function inside:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Windows;

namespace CryptoExceptionHandling {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            try {
                MakeCryptoException();
            } catch (CryptographicException x) {
                MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
            }
        }

        private void MakeCryptoException() {
            using (var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024, new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 })) {
                var data = new byte[128];
                new Random().NextBytes(data);
                csp.Decrypt(data, false);
            };

        }

    }
}
```

I expect this program to show me a message box with the exception. The program simulates a case, when some data provided to my app turned out invalid.

I don't want an application crash here, I want the application to do something more meaningful like showing "Access denied" or "Invalid data" screen.

How can I catch the exception? You can easily recreate this case by creating an empty `WPF` application and pasting the code below as `MainWindow.cs` content.

I deleted the previous content of this question, because as it can be observed in comments - it lacked a valid example.

Comment: "Somethings gone wrong but I can't show you any code, can people make guesses?"

Comment: `Exception is uncaught due to mysterious "managed/native boundary"` - most of the included cryptography providers are managed code around native code which is also why most of them are disposable (implement IDisposable). This is what the exception means, an error occurred in the native code (outside of the managed wrapper). As others have already mentioned you will have to provide additional details if you want any further useful help.

Comment: What algorithm, and how are you creating the instance?  For symmetric: CryptoStream or direct consumption? The closest hit my psychic debugging has is "you have an ICryptoTransform whose value of CanReuseTransform is false, but you reused it anyways", but that's entirely based on "it worked once, then failed".  You'll need to offer up some sort of minimal repro to get real help.

Comment: Sorry, that kind of bug. Can't paste code, it's top secret. Can make simpler example, too complex case. Still: @Igor - let's say the exception occured in unmanaged code - how can I make the app react to invalid data other than just crash? There's no way of testing the correctness of the key and data without trying to decrypt it.

Comment: 1. Exception != application crash. You can recover from an expected Exception using the catch and return what is necessary to the caller. 2. If your application relies on obfuscation for security you are doing it wrong. Encryption, decryption, hashing, etc. should rely on existing strong, proven, and secure providers. What makes it secure is the selected key(s) and not the code. If it is truly secure then it should not matter if the code is shared or not.

Comment: Finally you do not have to copy/paste your whole app as is, in fact that is discouraged. What is recommended is an MCVE, [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Ie: Just enough code for others to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I have to agree with @Igor on this one - you can't rely on the secrecy of your source code for your security, that's security through obscurity.

Comment: @EJoshuaS: It's not security by obscurity. This is a commercial application, I cannot disclose parts of it's source code. I have it strictly forbidden in my contract. The code is proprietary, and it is a property of my client. I use well tested and documented security libraries so again - it's all by the book. I just can't paste real sources because it's a proprietary code, that's all. BTW, I have the key rotation, and this is exactly which caused this exception in the first place. Now I just want to catch it.

Comment: I fixed the question, now it has reproducible example, crashes as charm ;) Thank you all for making me to make this right ;)

Comment: Hey, @Igor, I fixed my question as you advised, can you take a quick look at the example I made? I still can't catch the exception, even in basic, few lines sample.

Comment: Yes, an exception is thrown but the catch block handles it just fine (on my PC). The application shows the message box with the exception message (expected) and then still loads the main window (also expected). Is there anything else you are not telling us? Older .Net version maybe?

Comment: Weird, I get exception marked as unhandled in VS, using .NET Framework 4.5.2. Clicking "Continue" makes this unhandled exception reappear forever. Now I check the debugger options, see the "Break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries" option checked, uncheck it, than... it works. I must be terribly overworked and exhausted to miss such things. Thanks, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Go to DEBUG menu, Options submenu, uncheck "Break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries" option.

I debugged some mixed / unsafe code earlier and forgot to uncheck it when done.